# Fried Beaglebone Black. Would like confirmation to why

Tags: sensor

So I build open source grow room automation software but admittedly am a super noob when it comes to the electrical end of things.  Last night I attempted to run a dht22(temp and humidity) sensor an I wanted to solder it and use real wire rather than tacking together a bunch of jumper wires. I soldered everything up and on the beaglebone end, I just soldered the male end of jumper wires to my wire so they were able to easily plug in still.  On the sensor, I should have done the same but I decided to get tricky and try to solder my wire directly onto the sensor.  I desoldered the little jumpers that came on the sensor and soldered the wires directly on.

When I first booted the BBB all was fine but the system was not reading the sensor.  I took out a voltmeter and started to poke around.  I put my voltmeter on the continuity test.  When I touched the ground and hot I got a beep and I believe this is normal.  The part that I think may be the problem was it also beeped when I touched the ground to the data wire.  It seems like as soon as I touched them I got a beep and then the entire BBB went down for the count and is not able to come back up.  When I plug it in the power light flashes on for a micro second and then it goes dead.

Can anyone confirm what I did wrong and why?  I would really like to learn as much as possible from this experience.

Thank you!

Comment: What did you think putting your meter on continuity test was going to achieve?

Comment: The continuity test puts a voltage source in series with the meter input. That voltage is injected into the device under test. It may be a few volts. If you attached it wrong way, you had injected -3V  or so into your beagleboard. That fries the chips terminally.

Comment: @Finbarr I was hoping it would tell me if I accidentally connected the data to either the hot or gound as they are so close together and I assumed this was the root of the issue.  Being so new to this I was unaware that I could cause damage poking around with a voltmeter but I suppose this was a hard way to learn I was wrong

Comment: @Janka Thank you! So in the future, I should never run a continuity test on anything other than the negative and hot?  Feel free to explain things like I'm a child I'm still veryyyy new to electrical engineering and again thank you so much for the answer!  And just to make sure I fully understand... when I hit the data pin with the continuity test it injected a small but of voltage into my GPIO pin on the BBB and thats where the problem was correct?

Comment: You should not continuity test between something not a wire. So, don't touch random pins but always make sure at least one probe is connected to an open end, and the other before any part on the PCB.

Comment: You didn't poke around with a voltmeter, you poked around with a continuity tester. Understanding the difference is the main learning outcome here!

Comment: @Janka I believe I get what you are saying but just to be clear and make sure I'm not missing anything, technically I did only touch it to wires.  one of them just happened to be a wire going to a GPIO pin.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Janka for reference here is the sensor and the end of the wire I had plugged into the BBB via the soldered on male jumpers https://imgur.com/a/nAAgg

Comment: You have touched two wires with a continuity tester. That means you had the voltage source inside your tester attached to something on your board. There was a circuit over something on your board. And that's what fried it.